# Lipschitz function and incomplete range

Tags: general-topology, lipschitz-functions

Find a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that has incomplete range.

What is incomplete range of a function? Does it has to do with completeness of a metric space?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We couldn't possibly know for sure. Perhaps you should ask your teacher what he/she meant?

Comment: Probably the negation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space

Comment: Can you find a simple example in this case?

Comment: I found a theorem that says : if $f$ is an isometry then its range is complete. I believe it has to do with the image of $f$ and the range of the function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If by incomplete range we mean that the image $f(\Bbb R)$ of $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is not a complete subset of $\Bbb R$, then the function

$f(x) = \tanh x \tag 1$

provides an example.  It is everywhere continuously differentiable, which is sufficient for it to be
Lipschitz; but

$f(\Bbb R) = \tanh(\Bbb R) = (-1, 1), \tag 2$

which is incomplete as there are sequences $\alpha_i \in (-1, 1)$ such that

$\alpha_i \to -1, \; \text{or} \; \alpha_i \to 1 \; \text{as} \; i \to \infty, \tag 3$

but

$-1, \; 1 \notin (-1,  1). \tag 4$

Comment: I believe that's what we want. Thank you very much!

Comment: _"It is everywhere differentiable, which is sufficient for it to be Lipschitz"_. **Just no**: $x^2$.

Comment: You need $|f'(x)| = |\tanh'(x)| = |\mathrm{sech}(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: @Federico:  Both $\tanh x$ and $x^2$ are *locally* Lipschitz.  $\tanh x$ is *globally* Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant $1$, as your comment shows. I usually take the unqualified "Lipschitz" in the local sense.

Comment: @RobertLewis Your statement is false nonetheless: $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ is differentiable everywhere but not locally Lipschitz near $0$. Moreover "Lipschitz" alone generally means "globally Lipschitz". Functions which are differentiable everywhere already have a name: they are "differentiable everywhere". They are not Lipschitz

Comment: @Federico:  what is the derivative of $x^2 \sin (1/x^2)$ at $x = 0$?

Comment: @RobertLewis It is $0$. (Also the function is defined to be $0$, to be continuous)

Comment: @Federico:  it makes sense to define this function $x^2 \sin (1/x^2)$ to be $0$ at $0$, since $x^2 \to 0$ and $\sin (1/x^2)$ is bounded as $x \to 0$; how do you find $(x^2 \sin (1/x^2))'$ at $0$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Simply by definition: $|f(x)-f(0)|=|x^2\sin(1/x^2)-0| \leq x^2 = o(|x|)$, so the derivative is $0$